# Is there any method to check type of file before open it with wdDialogFileOpen?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I use wdDialogFileOpen to let user open file. I want to allow user to only open .docx file. Is there any method to check type of file before open it with wdDialogFileOpen (after user choose it with wdDialogFileOpen) ?
I use following code:

With Dialogs(wdDialogFileOpen) 
 .Name = "*.*" 
 .Show 
End With

Comment: Yes. There are filters you can apply to the dialog box if it is called using VBA. Amend your question to include the code you use to call the dialog box.

Comment: I have edited my question to include the code.

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
With Dialogs(wdDialogFileOpen)
  .Format = "*.docx"
  If .Display = True Then
    If InStrRev(.Name, ".docx") > 0 Then
      .Execute
    End If
  End If
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use the FileOpen dialog at all. Consider a FilePicker: The user selects the file and then you decide if you want to open it. Here is some code to play with.

```
Private Sub TestFileOpenName()

    Dim Fn As String
    Dim Sp() As String

    ' the Flt argument = 1 which results in Word documents being filtered
    Fn = FileOpenName("Select a file", 1, "C:\My Dopcuments\")

    ' the Flt argument = "Word documents|*.doc*" which also results in
    ' Word documents being filtered (modify filter as required)
'    Fn = FileOpenName("Select a file", "Word documents|*.doc*", "D:\My Dopcuments\")

    ' the Flt argument = 1 or 2 which results in Word documents being filtered
    ' but type drop-down allows changing to Excel.
    ' Specify "2||1" to make Excel the default and Word the alternative
'    Fn = FileOpenName("Select a file", "1||2", "C:\My Dopcuments\")

    If Len(Fn) Then
        MsgBox "The selected file is" & vbCr & Fn
        Sp = Split(Fn, ".")
        If InStr(1, Sp(UBound(Sp)), "doc", vbTextCompare) = 1 Then
            MsgBox "I will now open the document"
        Else
            MsgBox "Please select a Word document." & vbCr & _
                   "Sorry, I can't proceed."
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox "No file was selected"
    End If
End Sub

Function FileOpenName(ByVal Title As String, _
                      Optional ByVal Flt As Variant = 0, _
                      Optional ByVal Pn As String) As String
    ' SSY 050 ++ 14 Dec 2018

    ' ==================================================
    '   Parameters:
    '       Title             = Form's title
    '       Flt               = Specify filters by ID or string specs
    '                           separated by || (= 2 x Chr(124))
    '                           in sequence of position assignment.
    '                           Default = no filter [=All files]
    '       Pn                  = Initial path: [=Last used]
    ' ==================================================
    '   Note:   The ButtonName is "Open" by default. Another setting
    '           doesn't take effect until a file has been selected.
    ' ==================================================

    Const FltDesc As Long = 0, FltExt As Long = 1

    Dim Fod As FileDialog                           ' File Open Dialog
    Dim Fts() As String                             ' all filters
    Dim Sp() As String                              ' split filter
    Dim i As Long

    ' ==================================================

    Fts = Split(Flt, "||")
    ReDim Sp(3)
    Sp(1) = "Word documents|*.doc*"
    Sp(2) = "Excel workbooks|*.xls*"
    Sp(3) = "Image file|*.png, *.tif"
    For i = 0 To UBound(Fts)
        If IsNumeric(Fts(i)) Then Fts(i) = Sp(Fts(i))
    Next i

    Set Fod = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    With Fod
        .Filters.Clear
        For i = 0 To UBound(Fts)
            If Len(Fts(i)) Then
                Sp = Split(Fts(i), "|")
                .Filters.Add Sp(FltDesc), Sp(FltExt), i + 1
                .FilterIndex = 1
            End If
        Next i
        .Title = Title
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .InitialFileName = Pn
        If .Show Then FileOpenName = .SelectedItems(1)
    End With
End Function
```